# Can't query automatically indexed Documents

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I have documents in the form of JSON that I want to search. When I upload them to Solr I don't get any responses if q isn't * :*

I uploaded my documents via the simplePostTool. I type the following in cmd

```
java -jar -Dc=testdata -Dauto example/exampledocs/post.jar testdata.json
```

After I successfully uploaded that I try to query my data. If I just use * :* it shows me the data exactly how I want it. Like this:

```
{
        "number":[202012314],
        "category":["Lorem ipsum"]        
},{
```

Now, if I try to search for anything that is definitely in one of the documents it doesn't find anything.
What do I need to do to make my Collection searchable?

Comment: What is the query you're trying to use? What is the field types defined for those fields? What do you expect to get returned?

Comment: I'm trying to query every field. Most of those fields are of the type text_general. I'm just using the query tab in the admin panel, but the generated request looks like this: "http://localhost:8983/solr/testdata/select?indent=true&q.op=OR&q=ipsum"

Comment: That queryu isn't querying every field, it's query the default search field (`_text_` in the default configset - if you search against this field without content being copied into it, there will be no hits - every search is against a field, not "all fields"). Prefix your query with the field name: `category:ipsum` to actually search the `category` field.